# Create and download a clean CSV using PHP in a CMS

Tags: php, csv, content-management-system, export-to-csv, concrete5

I'm using Concrete5 CMS and I'm trying to allow users to download a subset of other users (ones they invited).

To do this, I am making a new page and using the following:

```
  $new_csv = fopen('members.csv', 'w');
  $array = array("foo", "bar", "hello", "world"); // For testing
  fputcsv($new_csv, $array);
  fclose($new_csv);

  header("Content-type: text/csv");
  header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename = members.csv");
  readfile("members.csv");
```

The problem I am having is this is writing the whole page.  Is there a way to do this possibly without using headers?  My approach is probably entirely off, so if there is a better way to achieve this, please let me know.

Comment: `die` the script after csv output ends.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean by "writing the whole page". Could you describe the issue in more detail?

Comment: I am using the CMS to pull user data which is relevant.  I want to output a CSV, but if I do it like this, it outputs all the CMS HTML.

Comment: @u_mulder, Can't believe it was that simple.  Please give it as answer and I will mark it correct?

Comment: `die` isn't the proper way. You should use `Core::make('app')->shutdown();`

Answer (score 2):

You may use `Core::make('app')->shutdown();` to fix this issue.

But for doing the export in a better way-
Check the `\Concrete\Controller\SinglePage\Dashboard\Users\Search::csv_export()` method.
It would be quite similar. Just set your filtered user list to `$writer->insertList($list)` method.